# JComboBox as CellRenderer does not set the correct value

Tags: swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecellrenderer

I'm using a JComboBox as CellRenderer in my JTable.
Everything works fine the JComboBox displays the correct item for the corresponding row.

The problem I am currently working on is that when I choose a new value in the JComboBox (for example row 9) the value is set correctly, but when I try to change the value in the next row, the JComboBox (for example in row 10) automatically sets the value of the row before.

I created a DropDownCellRenderer class which extends JComboBox and implements TableCellRenderer, I thought that is enough, but it seems that the DropDownCellRenderer-object is the same for every row.

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 3 ).setCellRenderer( new DropDownCellRenderer() );
table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 3 ).setCellEditor( new DefaultCellEditor( new DropDownCellRenderer() ) );
```

How can I avoid that every row uses the same object?

Comment: Your renderer implementation is probably incorrect, can we see it?

Comment: You can see the renderer implementation here: http://pastebin.com/Qg3Jf3C7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked at your renderer's source code.

1. I don't think you have to look up the Product by name. The `value` passed to you **is** the Product, which is coming from your table model (if it is implemented correctly). Just set the `value` as selected item and it should work.
2. To make renderer behave correctly, change its foreground and background colors according to `isSelected` parameter. The code should look like:

   ```
   if (isSelected) {
       setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
       super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
   } else {
       setForeground(table.getForeground());
       setBackground(table.getBackground());
   }
   ```
3. Make your initial array of values an argument of the constructor. This will transform your renderer into universal combobox renderer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're saving and displaying values within the combo box itself, not from the model of the table. When you set a value and save a combobox value you need to update the model